# d3.csv versus d3.text performance

Tags: javascript, performance, d3.js

Are there significant differences between using `d3.text(filepath, "text/csv", function)` and `d3.csv`? Are these equivalent or is one faster than the other?

Comment: `d3.csv` does additional parsing, but apart from that they should be identical -- they're both based on the same code.